# Containerized php:7.2-apache in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I have Containerized php application in dokcer and it was done and i want do the same in kubernetes and there are my files

**Dokcerfile**

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
COPY config/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
RUN  curl -sSLf \
        -o /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions \
        https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && \
    install-php-extensions mysqli
```

**deployment file**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: server-deployment
  labels:
    app: server
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: server
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: server
        image: ahmedelbagory288/testphp 
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: myapp-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/www/html/
      volumes:
      - name: myapp-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: myapp-pv-claim
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: server-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: server
  type: LoadBalancer  
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30000
```

**PersistentVolume file**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: myapp-pv
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  capacity:
   storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
   - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /media/bego/data/DevOps-Course/K8s Example/PHP/php my admin/app 
        
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: myapp-pv-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
   - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
   requests: 
    storage: 1Gi
```

i want to host my file where located in app folder in php:7.2-apache so i can view it
when i do **minikube service server-service**
it gives me

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) Server at 172.17.0.2 Port 30000
```

Comment: in your docker file are you adding the index files and other necessary files ?

Comment: @HarshManvar yes